# Image preview only working with the first image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My js code previews the image which is selected in the input  field. Works fine generally.

In this case I have 15 images in a page which open in a modal on click. 
User can click on any image and upload a new one and it will appear.

It's working with the first image only . Not working for the other images.

Is it because of the modal or should I change JS code ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
              $(document).ready(function(){
        function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                      
               $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                     }
                    
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
           
                }
            }
                
                 $("#imgInp").change(function(){
                readURL(this);
            });
                
         });
        </script>

   
<div id="myModal_<?php echo $post_slug;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Post</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                
          <div id="edit_post">
          
          
          </div>
          <div >
          <span class="input-btn">
                <button class="browse btn btn-danger input-md" type="button">< change</button>
              </span>
          
         
          </div>
           
          <img id="blah"  src="images/<?php echo $post_image3;?>"   />
          
           <input type="file" name="image" class="file" id="imgInp"/>
          
          
           
           
           
          
        </form>
          
          </div>
          
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button  style="float: left;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <span  >  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="saveedit" > Save </button></span>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if that was the problem then  it would not work for the first image .... src is not the problem here ...it works from anywhere

Comment: To clarify..the page is preloaded with 15 images and then the user can replace any of those 15 with an image upload from their own computer (which you want them to preview)?

Comment: yes thats it ............

Comment: inside of your readUrl function add either console.log("I am called") if you know where the developer console is in the browser OR add alert("I am called").  THen test again. If the log or alert happens for every image then it is in the readURl function. If not, it's the .change() and input aren't working the way you expect.